# Alternative to use-case of friendship inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

I have a data structure, and two classes accessing it:

```
   class Foo {
     public:
       void set(double foo);
       double get();
   };

   class FooWriter {
     Foo bar;
     void setFoo() { bar.set(42); }
   };

   class FooReader {
     Foo *baz;
     double getFoo() { return baz->get(); }
   };
```

I would like to restrict FooReader to read Foo, and allow setting only for FooWriter. Private set function and friend class would be an option but unfortunately I have a lot of subclasses of FooWriter, and since friendship can not be inherited, I would not like to list them all as friends. Bypassing encapsulation with protected method in friend FooWriter superclass is an other option:

```
   class Foo {
       void set(double foo);
     public:
       double get();
       friend class FooWriter;
   };

   class FooWriter {
     Foo bar;
     protected:
     void setFooBackdoor(double value) { bar.set(value); }
   };

   class subFooWriter {
     void setFoo() { setFooBackdoor(42); }
   };
```

but some would consider this as bad design. I've also read here that if you need friendship inheritence, there is a flaw in your design, so I'm curious, what would be the proper solution for this problem.

Comment: Foo has members in the actual code but I moved them out to have a short example.